# Apache Superset remote connection to PostgreSQL database: Can't determine Superset IP

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, apache-superset

I'm running a Superset instance via Docker on a MacBook Air (2019, v11.5.2, Intel i5). I'm trying to set up a remote connection to a PostgreSQL database via an AWS endpoint. I entered the credentials via the dynamic form, as such:

- HOST: {dbalias}.{xyz}.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
- PORT: 5432
- DATABASE: {dbname}
- USERNAME: {username}
- PASSWORD: {password}

I'm sure that my credentials are valid because I used them to connect from both Databox and DBeaver. But when I try to connect here, Superset tells me that port 5432 is closed. A little digging tells me that this is likely a firewall issue.

I know that our database is set up to only allow connections from allowed IPs, and of course my machine's IP is whitelisted, so I assume I need to whitelist the IP that is sending the connection request (i.e., Superset). However, I cannot seem to find that information. Indeed, even [Superset's PostgreSQL connection instructions](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/postgres) seem to be incomplete vis-a-vis connecting to an AWS endpoint.

Assuming I've diagnosed the problem correctly (which is by no means a guarantee), the key question is: **Where can I find my Superset instance's IP to add to my PostgreSQL IP whitelist?** Relatedly, would this IP change next time I launch Superset from Docker, or will it persist?

Many thanks for any consideration.

Comment: Applications running on your laptop will be seen by an AWS service as connecting from your laptop's IP, or, if it's behind a NATting router, from that of your router.

Comment: @mustaccio Thank you. If you please, since my IP is whitelisted, any idea why I might still be getting that "this port is closed" error when I try to connect? Bearing in mind that I can connect to the db via the same port and credentials from other clients.